# Why thread is interrupted before the changes are complete

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm attempting to create python module for getting MAC adresses by IP addresses.

```
def getMACs(addressesList):
    def _processArp(pkt):
        spa = _inet_ntoa(pkt.spa) 
        if pkt.op == dpkt.arp.ARP_OP_REPLY and spa in _cache.macTable:
            lock.acquire()
            try:
                _cache.macTable[spa] = _packedToMacStr(pkt.sha)
                _cache.notFilledMacs -= 1
            finally:
                lock.release()
            if _cache.notFilledMacs == 0:
                thrd.stop()

    addresses = _parseAddresses(addressesList)

    _cache.registerCacheEntry("macTable", {})
    _cache.registerCacheEntry("notFilledMacs", 0)
    _events.arpPacket += _processArp

    lock = threading.Lock()

    thrd = _CaptureThread(promisc=False, timeout_ms=30, filter="arp")
    thrd.start()
    for addr in addresses:
        if _sendArpQuery(addr):
            _cache.macTable[str(addr)] = None
            _cache.notFilledMacs += 1
    thrd.join(125)
    thrd.stop()
    return _cache.macTable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    macTable = getMACs([IPAddress("192.168.1.1"), IPAddress("192.168.1.3")])
    _pprint.pprint(macTable)
```

When I run this module I get

```
{'192.168.1.1': '00:11:95:9E:25:B1', '192.168.1.3': None}
```

When I debug _processArp step by step I get

```
{'192.168.1.1': '00:11:95:9E:25:B1', '192.168.1.3': '00:21:63:78:98:8E'}
```

Class CaptureThread:

```
class CaptureThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self, name=None, snaplen=65535, promisc=True, timeout_ms=0, immediate=False, filter=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__running = True
        self.__name = name 
        self.__snaplen = snaplen 
        self.__promisc = promisc 
        self.__timeout_ms = timeout_ms 
        self.__immediate = immediate 
        self.__filter = filter 

    def stop(self):
        self.__running = False

    def run(self):
        self.__pc = pcap.pcap(self.__name, self.__snaplen, self.__promisc, self.__timeout_ms, self.__immediate)
        if self.__filter:
            self.__pc.setfilter(self.__filter)

        while self.__running:
            self.__pc.dispatch(1, self.__processPacket)

    def __processPacket(self, timestamp, pkt):
        peth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)
        if isinstance(peth.data, dpkt.arp.ARP):
            _events.arpPacket(peth.data)
```

Comment: _This __code ___is ____very _____hard ______to _______read.

Comment: Are all of the _variables declared at the module level?

Comment: Wait, they're being assigned to, but not declared `global` within those functions.  Okay.. I expected them to be module-level, because that would explain the significance of _starting _them _with _underscores.  What's the reason for that?

Comment: Double underscores are NOT a replacement of private. The double underscore was introduced to be used by a parent class, to prevent name clashes with its child class, especially when the parent class is written by a different developer than the child class. As such, in general, in python, it's frowned upon to use double underscore or single underscore indiscriminately.

Comment: More importantly, you should be supplying code that people can run, not unrunnable snippets expecting people to just squint at it.  Please isolate the problem you're asking about and provide a self-contained block of code that we can copy to a file and test.

Comment: What happens if you increase the join() timeout?

Comment: Sorry for complex code. But problem is complex and I am afraid that to isolate the problem in a small piece of runnable code will not work.

Comment: I'm really a bit too far with underscores.

@intuited _cache and _events is imports from other modules. _thrd and _lock - unnecessary underscores.

Comment: @Russell Borogove Timeout 125 sec for debugging. I think it makes no sense to increase it.

Comment: @Lie Ryan I use __members to indicate that these members should not be used outside of class. I use _variables to indicate that these variables should not be used outside of module as module members. These _variables AFAIK are not imported by "from <modulename> import *" and are not displayed with the command help. _thrd and _lock - it is mistake, a consequence of long experiments.

Comment: @Artem Andreev: that's equivalent to making things private in python. In python 99.99% of the time, you shouldn't use double underscore. If you want to mark: "implementation details use at your own risk", then a single underscore is sufficient. The double underscore invokes a name-mangling scheme, and should only be used when you're designing a class that will be inherited by many other classes, and you want to avoid name clashes with the children.

Comment: @Lie Ryan Thanks! You are definitely right. I tried to use command "help" for class with _members - all work nice. Another use case for __members - it is easy to find the use of private members careless programmers. But this is controversial use case...

Comment: @Artem Andreev: if programmers used your underscored name, they basically accepts that their code will break if you change your code, you don't need to bother with breaking their code. However, in Python, generally you won't even need to use single underscore since python's @property can transparently replace the old attribute, if you ever need to change them. The practice of making everything private is not so pervasive in Python, compared to in other languages (e.g. Java, C/C++) where it is impossible to transparently replace an attribute with a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid error. As always when working with threads - because of thread synchronization.

One of my conditions for interrupting thread is "_cache.notFilledMacs == 0". In the main thread _cache.notFilledMacs did not have time to get the value of 2 when in the CaptureThread value is decreased.